# Validate XML instance document against WSDL

Tags: validation, xsd, wsdl

I can easily validate a **XML document** against a **XML Schema**, eg. with **XMLSpy** or programmatically. 
Is it possible to do this with a **WSDL** file? It does not seem possible with **XMLSpy** or any other XML tool I know. For me the only possibility right now is to do it programmatically, eg. by generating Java code from the **WSDL** and starting a request, which is then marshalled correctly.
If there is no tool / easy programmatic approach, is there a tool which can extract **XML Schema** from the **WSDL**?

Best

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[QTAssistant](http://paschidev.com) (I am associated with it) provides an easy to use utility to extract XSDs from any-style WSDL (single or multiple file, internalized or externalized XSDs).

[image: QTAssistant Externalize XSDs from WSDL]

The prompt is pretty straightforward to follow, and provides a lot of flexibility in referencing offline WSDLs (local disk) or remote (HTTP/S).

[image: QTAssistant Externalize XSDs from WSDL prompt]

Another feature that works well with the above set is the ability to validate a SOAP envelope against an XSD, also available within QTAssistant; there's a property **Strip SOAP** for an XML document that'll automatically validate SOAP Body content against assign XSD.

[image: Strip SOAP envelope for validation]

Answer (score 12):

You could use [SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org/) :

- Create new project (you'll need to provide wsdl)
- Double click on the "request" of your new project
- Modify XML if needed
- Right click -> validate